# Print data in next line when we found double space in our paragraph

Tags: php

$pro_spec = Gary Keller is co-founder and chairman of Keller Williams Realty, the largest real estate franchise in the world.  He is the New York Times bestselling author of numerous books, including The Millionaire Real Estate Agent,  The Millionaire Real Estate Investor, SHIFT: How Top Real Estate Agents Tackle Tough Times, and, most recently,  The ONE Thing: The Surprisingly Simple Truth Behind Extraordinary Results.

```
enter code <?php 

                $result = str_split($pro_pros);

                $length = count($result);

                for($i=0;$i<$length-1;$i++)
                {                    
                    if($result[$i] == " " && $result[$i+1] == " ")    
                    {
                        $substring = substr($pro_pros,isset($bun)? $bun+1 : 0 ,$i+1);

                            echo $substring

                            $bun = $i+1;                                                
                     }

                 }

             ?>here
```

I want to print data in next line when I got double space in $pro_spec.
But After I run above code I got output like this

Gary Keller is co-founder and chairman of Keller Williams Realty, the largest real estate franchise in the world.

He is the New York Times bestselling author of numerous books, including The Millionaire Real Estate Agent, The Millionaire Real Estate Investor, SHIFT: How Top Real Estate Agents Tackle Tough Times, and, most recently,
The Millionaire Real Estate Investor, SHIFT: How Top Real Estate Agents Tackle Tough Times, and, most recently, The ONE Thing: The Surprisingly Simple Truth Behind Extraordinary Results.

The ONE Thing: The Surprisingly Simple Truth Behind Extraordinary Results.

Same data occur in multiple line how can I solve this..

Comment: Now format your question to be understandable.

Comment: You have some invalid content in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string into an array when there are double spaces, and then echo each line with whatever line break you want in between.:

```
<?php 

$result = explode('  ', $pro_pos);
foreach ($result as $line) {
    echo $line . '<br />';
}

?>
```